# Enable FTP Publishing on IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, ftp

I've followed the steps in

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/303/adding-ftp-to-a-web-site/

However, when I get to the part where it says to click "add ftp publishing to website", the option is not visible in the IIS management console.

I've verified that the "FTP Publishing Service" is installed in the server manager, and I can see it running in the services applet and via netstat -a.

Suggestions?

Comment: are you on 2008 or 2008R2 (or Vista or Win7)?

Comment: 2008 64-bit, iis 7.0

Comment: Try stopping and restarting IIS Manager.

Comment: @RenniePet that was in 2010. I fixed it. And changed fields. But, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. (I realized it was an old thread, but added my comment to help others who may have experienced what I'd just experienced, and Googled it, and found themselves here.)

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the steps as mentioned [here](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-FTP-Publishinge280a6-in-IIS-7-75.aspx).

Comment: As I said, "add FTP publishing" doesn't show in the actions pane in iis manager, though the service is installed and running.